# Gradle can't fetch dependencies when setting up a Unity project

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I am getting this error while setting up unity project for android 
Gradle failed to fetch dependencies.

[image: Error log]

<sub>(Note: this error log is redacted. See the screenshot above for more info)</sub>

```
Gradle failed to fetch dependencies.

stderr: Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
  at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1252) 
  at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1153) 
  at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1160) 
  at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:997)
  at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:960)
  at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:216)
  at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:148)
  at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:162)
  at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:215)
  at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
  at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:75)
  at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
  at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
  at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
  at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
  at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
exit code: 1
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object) Google.Logger:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey14:<>m__1F(Result)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey15:<>m__28()
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:PumpUpdateQueue()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
```

Comment: Its continue happening on my macbook, I am not a android developer, I have only unity3d coding knowledge.

Comment: Please provide your code, not a screenshot. See [ask].

Comment: Are you running it from macOS, or Bootcamp (Windows)? It seems that it's macOS since `Bootcamp` is in the `/Volumes` directory. In this case, I'm pretty sure that you can't read/write from Bootcamp.

Comment: I edited the title of your question to include the error and the event that you did which caused this error. I've also updated your screenshot to use Imgur instead of Dropbox. Lastly, I've updated the error log that you posted in a blockquote to become a code block. Anyways, could you specify if you're running macOS or Windows?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response on this,

Comment: I am still stuck with this issue, I was using another pc ( a window pc ) , and thats working fine, but this error was on mac, and its still not resolved.